# How do I define a certificate resource in my ARM template when it is hosted in the Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to define an ARM template for my resource group.  Ultimately I'm trying to replicate what I have to do manually by navigating to the SSL certificates tab for an App Service within the portal.

I've uploaded a PFX file to the Secrets tab of my KeyVault.  I've granted **Get** access to the global RM service principal.

At the moment this is what my `Microsoft.Web/certificates` resource looks like in my template.  It is just defined as a resource at the top level of the resource group, and not as a sub-resource of a website or anything like that:

```
    {
        "type":"Microsoft.Web/certificates",
        "name": "signingCredentials",
        "location": "[parameters('region')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "properties": {
            "keyVaultId": "<My KeyVault ID>",
            "keyVaultSecretName": "<My Secret Name>"
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to deploy this template I receive the message:

> The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this parameter and what value it would be expecting.  I'm assuming it's missing from the `properties` section in the resource.  So far anything I've found on the subject only references `keyVaultId` and `keyVaultSecretName`.

What am I doing wrong?  Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not appear to be caused by my template, but something with how the certificate was uploaded to the KeyVault through the UI.  [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/deploying-azure-web-app-certificate-through-key-vault/) provided me a script to upload the file directly to the KeyVault using powershell.

```
$pfxFilePath = "F:\KeyVault\PrivateCertificate.pfx"
$pwd = "[2+)t^BgfYZ2C0WAu__gw["
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable 
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection  
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag) 
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12 
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType) 
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes) 
$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $fileContentEncoded -AsPlainText –Force 
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12' 
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName akurmitestvault -Name keyVaultCert -SecretValue $Secret -ContentType $secretContentType # Change the Key Vault name and secret name
```

Using the `Get-AzureKeyVault` script from Jambor's answer, I am unable to see any difference between the certificate uploaded in the UI. I even changed the content type of my uploaded certificate from **Certificate** to **application/x-pcks2** and it still did not work.  Seems like it might possibly a bug in the UI, or just a difference in how the powershell script handles it.

Comment: I tried this solution and I'm still getting the same error message. I'm trying to use a self signed cert that I created via PS>New-SelfSignedCertificate, but I wouldn't think that would cause an issue.

Comment: If you create a certificate directly from key vault in the Portal, make sure you select the PKCS#12 version (not PEM), this answer pointed me in the right direction thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value

It seems that this issue is not caused by your template. We can refer to [this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-certificate-from-key-vault/azuredeploy.json) to check it. From the error message, it shows me that the certification name is incorrect. We can use  `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret` to get its name. The following is details:

[image]

As above screenshot, the value "kvcertificate" is the value we expected.

Comment: Jambor, unfortunately that does not seem to be the case.  The issue appears to be with certificates that I upload through the portal UI.  If I upload the file through a powershell script it works